# What are some fast and simple implementations for a segmented progress bar in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, controls

More specifically, I tried having a grid of 48 rows, 40 units high, contained in a scroll viewer... each row was to contain a progress bar, but for whatever reason, this really REALLY slowed down my user interface, so I've scrapped it. My questions are as follows:

Why would the progress bar cause such extreme slowdown, especially while the host panel is animating?

In place of a progress bar, I could use a multi-column grid and fill it with rects that change size and can be individually colored, would this be a "faster" solution?

Comment: What's a "segmented progress bar" - do you need to visually overlaw markers or other details? I bet the 40 controls are just rather intense - a lot of events, all probably full of storyboards that are animating (if you're using the IsIndeterminate property), etc.

Comment: I'm actually not :-/  just using a progress bar... as in <ProgressBar />

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but Chapter 3 of WPF Control Development Unleashed contains an example for a "staged" ProgressBar. (SAMS Publishing , Pavan Podila & Kevin Hoffman)

Answer (score 0):

Animations (can) cost CPU time. So less animation/calculation/rendering for the progress bar will cost less CPU time.

The standard [WPF progress bar is notorious for its animation](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/progressbar-performance-problems-88482.shtml).

A progress bar with a simpler design is probably better than the default one.

Your solution with a 40 rows grid and 40 progress bars is no good: too many calculations.

You could try to replace the template of the progress bar but 40 progress bars is still a lot. Perhaps another way of showing progress (numbers?) might be better for performance.